# What is the difference between "strong personality" and "strong character"?

Tags: difference

Tell me please what is the difference between *strong personality* and *strong character*? For example:

> Kate has a strong personality.
>
> Kate has a strong character.

Comment: One's **personality** is about interaction with other people. To survive being marooned alone in winter, you need a strong **character** (unless the wildlife reacts well to your personality).

Comment: @WeatherVane To me, the first part of your sentence is wonderful. It seems you used to use the participle clause, right? Could you rewrite your sentence without participle clause? Thanks

Comment: In contemporary English, one rarely uses character like that. You are or are not some kind of character, especially in acting.

Comment: [Both are reasonably common,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=She+has+a+strong+personality%2CShe+has+a+strong+character&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) and I don't think many people would recognise any difference in *meaning*. (And imho the few people that ***do*** think there's a difference are simply mistaken! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before I share my thoughts here is what the internet says about the term "**strong personality**":

- [strong personality](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/strong_personality) - The qualities of *self-confidence* and *assertiveness* in a person.

> *She is a successful leader because of her **strong personality.***

- an aggressive person; a difficult person, a bitch.

> *She has a **strong personality***

A strong character is way different in definition. My opinion is that a strong character means that the person is strong-willed and doesn't allow others to control him in any way, manipulate or influence the mind. Such people have their own opinion which is firm and they are stubborn in terms of reaching their goal. However, many people will have a different point of view on the definitions of these words.

Answer (score 1):

1. A strong personality is saying that Kate has either a lot of charisma, or is very stubborn.
2. A strong character is saying that Kate is very moral and likely to do what is right.